# batch set shutdown temp variable

Tags: batch-file

I try to make a .bat file for shutdown the pc after answer the user the time but not work:

```
SET /P /A temp_var=set time to shutdown:
start "" shutdown -s -f -t %temp_var
exit
```

Nothing happen ( I run it with administrator privileges )

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Whats wrong?

```
SET /P /A temp_var=set time to shutdown:
```

You can't use both `/p` and `/a` with `set`. Choose one of them.

```
Syntax
      SET variable
      SET variable=string
      SET /A "variable=expression"
      SET "variable="
      SET /P variable=[promptString]
      SET "
```

Source [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

In your case it looks like you need to use only `set /p`

---

```
start "" shutdown -s -f -t %temp_var
```

Variable names in batch files are delimited with `%` at each end.

> Variables have a percent sign on both sides: %ThisIsAVariable%

Source [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)

Replace `%temp_var` with `%temp_var%`.

---

Corrected batch file:

```
SET /P temp_var=set time to shutdown:
start "" shutdown -s -f -t %temp_var%
exit
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) - Environment variables are mainly used within batch files, they can be created, modified and deleted for a session using the SET command.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

Comment: But you are in the good direction ... if i set manually SET /A temp_var=3600 it work  but I need to ask user before. So with /A work but don't ask with /P ask but don't work

Comment: @MTK See corrected answer. I forgot to add the extra `%` in the corrected batch file :/